# How can I make a web.config tranformation on the TFS2017 for ASP.NET application

Tags: c#, tfs, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I have a continuous integration process running in my tfs2017. What I don't know is how to configure the .config file in build time to reflect the proper web.config per environment. Is there also anyway to achieve this by just making a configuration per environment? not with Tokenization

I have friends that recommend me to follow their steps but I am seeing that they can configure the build definition through the visual studio, but in my case every time I am clicking in a new Build Definition redirects me to the tfs online. Also they have a magic step Items to Build where they choose the definitions to transform.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, your friend is supposed to use old XAML build system and they should have customized the build process template.

Actually, we don't recommend using old XAML build system, instead, we suggest you stay with the new build system. Adding Tokenization Task would be the easiest way to transform file, otherwise, you would have to write your own script.

Comment: Actually I want to avoid the tokenization, is there anyway to do it per environment?.I need the opposite, do you have any link that you suggest to read?

Comment: What's the reason that you avoid the tokenization? How about these extensions: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=transform&target=VSTS&sortBy=Relevance?